.NET MAUI Community toolkit - cannot center child views inside a Popup
If I create a MAUI popup and I add a few labels, entries and buttons in a vertical stack layout, they appear at the top of the popup leaving an unaesthetic gap at the bottom.
The problem:
Issue on a read Android device:

Issue on a Pixel 5 simulator:

Same code works fine in a ContentPage:

VS 17.9.6 (tried 17.11.0 and got same result)
.NET8
CommunityToolkit.MAUI 7.0.1 (tried 9.0.0 and got same results)
Initially I though to set VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" or VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" on all the child views expecting them to space out vertically evenly. This didn't worked and it seems that it is not supposed to work:
"Therefore, a vertically oriented StackLayout ignores the Start, Center, End, or Fill fields if they are set on the VerticalOptions properties of child views"
source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/align-position?view=net-maui-8.0
I tough to try to set the Popup height be same as the sum of the heights of the child views. I can't do this because the Popup constructor is requesting me to say how big the Popup should be (which I think is irritating because in some applications, I may want to programmatically show of hide fields so I don't know how big it has to be)
Eventually I tried adding VerticalOptions="Center" to the main StackLayout. This solution works on a content page (if I paste the code in a content page), however it doesn't work on a Popup. I tried setting VerticalOptions="Center" to the Popup itself and hasn't worked.
Any of the below solutions would solve the issue but could not implement any of them:

center the child views vertically
evenly space out vertically child views
make popup height be as big as the sum of the child views
XAML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup x:Class="SLtest.SaveDialog"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
            CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Blue">
        <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="NotesSL" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
            <Label x:Name="NotesLbl" Text="Notes"/>
            <Entry x:Name="NotesEntry"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="USFsl" BackgroundColor="LightCoral">
            <Label x:Name="USFlbl" Text="USF"/>
            <Entry x:Name="USFentry"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width = "1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width = "1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Text="Cancel"
                    Margin="10,0"/>
            <Button Text="Save"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                    Margin="10,0"
                    Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</mct:Popup>

C#:
    using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
    using SLtest.classes;
    
    namespace SLtest;
    
    public partial class SaveDialog : Popup
    {
        public SaveDialog(PopupSizeConstants popupSizeConstants)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    
            Size = popupSizeConstants.Medium;
            ResultWhenUserTapsOutsideOfPopup = "User Tapped Outside of Popup";
        }
    
        async void Button_Clicked(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            await CloseAsync("Close button tapped", cts.Token);
        }
    }


I test the code you provide and it works well on my side. My environment is VS 17.9.6 .NET8 CommunityToolkit.MAUI 9.0.0

It's probably better to use a Grid at the root level of the popup. Have you tried that?

Hi @Julian, I tried with a grid but could not resolve the gap the bottom. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Hi @JianweiSun-MSFT, I tried on a Android simulator on Pixel 5, API 33 with MAUI community toolkit 9.0.0 and got same result (I added screen shot in the post). Is it possible to receive your project example to run it on my machine?

I create a project and add a Popup that the code you provided:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup x:Class="SLtest.SaveDialog"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
            CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Blue">
        <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="NotesSL" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
            <Label x:Name="NotesLbl" Text="Notes"/>
            <Entry x:Name="NotesEntry"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="USFsl" BackgroundColor="LightCoral">
            <Label x:Name="USFlbl" Text="USF"/>
            <Entry x:Name="USFentry"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width = "1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width = "1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Text="Cancel"
                    Margin="10,0"/>
            <Button Text="Save"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                    Margin="10,0"
                    Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</mct:Popup>

But I do not add this line of code:
Size = popupSizeConstants.Medium;

Set WidthRequest of VertialStackLayout to 250, here is the effect.

Ohh, great, I though it was mandatory to set the Size property of the popup.


Center the child views vertically within the popup:
To center the child views vertically, you can set the VerticalOptions of the VerticalStackLayout to "FillAndExpand" instead of "Center".

Evenly space out the child views vertically within the popup:
To evenly space out the child views vertically, you can add Spacing property to the VerticalStackLayout.


3.Make the popup height be as big as the sum of the child views:
To make the popup height adjust according to the content, you might want to set the HeightRequest property of the VerticalStackLayout to a fixed value or bind it dynamically to the sum of the heights of the child views.

Note that the *AndExpand layout options are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Oh yes sorry for that.

Thanks for the answer, 1. yes, FillAndExpand seems to work but is deprecated. 2. The spacing property does space the child views but the spacing will probably always be too little or too much. Ideally, the code should decide automatically how much to space it out to have it nicely spread across the popup area. 3. I tried setting HeightRequest (and also tried minimum and maximum height requests) for the vertical stack layout but none seem to have any effect. I found a post on stackoverflow which helped me to make it work decently (will post the code)

Found this on stack overflow and managed to get it to look nice.
Make popup size to be always equal to the size of its content
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup x:Class="SLtest.SaveDialog"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
            CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
            Color="Transparent">
    <Grid>
        <Frame VerticalOptions="Center" BorderColor="Transparent">
            <Grid RowSpacing="10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Text="USF:" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Entry Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <Label Text="Notes:" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
                <Entry Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3"/>
                <Button Text="Cancel" Margin="10" Grid.Row="4"/>
                <Button Text="Save" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"/>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</mct:Popup>

Hiding/unhiding child views in grid makes the popup automatically resize its height (which is good).
One other problem was how the popup would appear if user rotated device AFTER displaying the popup.
The solution is not elegant, but on Android it seems to do what I need it to do. In the constructor of PopupSizeConstants class I defined this custom size:
   double size = Math.Max(deviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width, deviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height) / deviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density * 0.8;
   Custom = new(size, size); //this way we get good size in both landscape and portrait

